# How can I make border of checkbox visible in kendo mobile

Tags: kendo-ui

I use checkbox in kendo ui for mobile. I can not find option to make the borders of checkbox visible. Does somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be different depending on the device/skin being used (IOS/Android, Flat, Material etc.) but you should be able to just set the border on the checkbox.

```
.km-check {
    border: thin solid black !important;
}
```

See sample.  http://jsbin.com/befona/1/edit?html,css,js,output

You may have to tweak font-size etc. to get it to line up correctly.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! it was my solution also but a problem (for me) that in apple it looks ugly:)